# vim macro for substitution with confirmation

Tags: vim

I want to write macro for substitution with confirmation, something like `:%s/old/new/gc`, where old and new are constantly changing (they are dynamically constructed by the same macro). but i cant stop recording the macro while typing colon command, and after entering that command, i have confirmation prompt `replace with new (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?` As you see, typing `q` now will quit the substitute command, and not stop the macro.

So, what i want:
i want macro, which will execute `:%s/old/new/gc` as i need to confirm each substitution.
Or some other automated solution for that problem. Maybe there is a way to stop recording macro while entering a colon command?

Comment: I am feeling that this is a XY problem. can you tell something about your real problem? what do you want to do with your text?

Comment: got a bunch of lines like `<field name="a:fact" class="java.lang.String"/>`  and i need to add ` sld-` prefix before each field name like that `<field name="a:sld-fact" class="java.lang.String"/>`. and those names are also present in the rest of the file, so they also should be renamed. **BUT** I can not use plain substitution, as i  got situations like next field will be `<field name="a:cult-fact" class="java.lang.String"/>`, so i need to replace first name `fact` with `sld-fact` and second `cult-fact`with `sld-cult-fact`, so i need possibility to choose which occurence of `fact` to replace

Answer (score 0):

You could try regular expressions for the search replace. The following should do what's described above.

`%s/a:\(\w\{-}-\{-}fact\)/a:sld-\1/gc`

See:

http://vimregex.com/

http://regexone.com/